# Wildcard for a column name in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, wildcard

Is it possible to have a wildcard in a column name specified in the WHERE clause? I want to select something but only if a bunch of columns match a certain value (1 in this case). For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM records WHERE *_check = 1
```

I have a bunch of columns that have _check as the suffix and it would be really nice to use something similar to the above code (which doesn't work).

Comment: There isn't and there shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will scrap that idea and just go the route of making a view.

Comment: I doubt a view will help you. You need to dynamically construct your query, which is easy to do from language like PHP / Ruby / Python / <insert language of preference>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could query the information_schema to get the columns in one query

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'foo'
 AND table_name = 'bar'
 AND column_name LIKE '%_check'
```

and build your query from the result (pseudo code)

```
query = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM records WHERE ";

foreach columName in columnNames
   query = query + " " + column_name + " = 1 OR "
next

query = TrimLastOr(query);
```

But I wouldn't recommend that because mysql information_schema query have a poor performance since they read from disk for every query.

Better: Use a view that returns

```
SELECT id FROM records WHERE col1_check=1 or col2_check=2 ...
```

so you can use it in your logic on multiple places, and only have to update the view if you add another `_check` column.

Comment: I like your idea of using a view. That should work well for what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you want to do something like this, you need the equivalent of dynamic SQL.

Comment: Dynamic SQL which would fetch the column name through the sys.columns table.

Comment: @RajivVarma - as you might have noticed, the question is about MySQL. There is no `sys.columns` there.

Comment: My bad. I didnt see what DBMS the question was about.