# Coalesce Using LIKE % - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, coalesce

```
SELECT 
COALESCE (chars.CFWEMAIL,
          chars.CLMEMAIL,
          chars.HLDEMAIL,
          chars.IFREMAIL)                   
                   email
FROM tmp
```

I am trying to achieve the above without hardcoding the columns into the coalesce statement.

Can I use LIKE % instead?

```
Coalesce all columns LIKE '%MAIL'
```

Comment: You cannot do that in Oracle . . . unless you use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Comment: and even with dynamic SQL (server-side or client-side), you have to get the list of columns from somewhere first.

Comment: No. LIKE works on character columns, not column names.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116292/match-multiple-columns-with-same-value-sql?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797686/selecting-all-columns-that-start-with-xxx-using-a-wildcard

Comment: You can't do that in any relational database which uses SQL - the `LIKE` operator doesn't operate on column *names*, it operates on column *contents*.